Window Screen Track
Anyone have any suggestions for making my own window screen tracks? The windows in place are a bit older (wooden windows) and don't have tracks for screens. Anything I can use to screw onto the exterior as a track and then make custom fit screens with spring clips to make it snug but able to move up and down?

Please see [ask]. Your question is too broad. We're not a discussion forum.

Simple mounting clips may make more sense than unsightly tracks.

Please post photos of the old track and the window.

I have done that with U-shaped extruded Aluminum profiles that I screwed on to the window frame.
For screen, I used pre-made screen profiles  found at any hardware store. Those have a spring to keep them snug and allow sliding up and down.

found on spring
